# Hello world attempt at composition with doughnut tutorial, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: compositing-nodes, compile

I'm trying to composite a set of rendered frames on top of a photo of the beach. This works if I'm rendering the whole 3D scene,  but I was trying to use the strip of pre-rendered images, in OpenEXR format, each with their own alpha channel.  (I completed the Blender Guru beginners tutorial)

Following this tip on Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/rl1g1m/how_to_change_compositing_after_rendering_image/

This is what I have come up with:

[image: Screenshot of composite workspace] Using the Image Sequence instead of the Render Layers at the start,  an image source,  the 'Alpha Over node' and the compose node for output.  You can see in the screenshot that the output preview looks perfect. However, when I click F12 to render a single frame,  I can only see the doughnut with the checkered background.

[image: Just the doughnut in preview]. If I Shift F12, Render Animation, I get a complete MP4, but with a black background.

Closing the preview, now the small preview is wrong too;
[image: Small image preview missing]

I select the Composite node,  then click 'reset node' in the node properties panel and the preview panel looks correct again, as far as I know, I didn't change any of the composite settings to reset, this feels like a bug.

Turning Compositing on or off in 'Output -> Post Processing' makes no difference, although turning off 'Sequencer' gives me a completly black 300 frames.

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file, thx

Comment: Hello, Silly question that has to be asked, first.. is Compositing in your pipeline? https://imgur.com/a/Q3dbWOL

Comment: Yes, it is. Turning Compositing on or off in 'Output -> Post Processing' makes no difference, although turning off 'Sequencer' gives me a completely black 300 frames. Also, the last node is 'Composite' @RobinBetts

Comment: @Chris What's the best way to do that?

Comment: open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=84P1mJgx" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/84P1mJgx/) Their T&C's are pretty extreme. Even with throwaway rubbish like this, I feel a bit awkward.